# Troubleshooting Webscrape in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to do something pretty simple and capture the price for each Amazon link I list. My issue is that the results are always NA.

My code

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
web_scrape <- function(page) 
{
        web <- read_html(page)
              data.frame(Buyboxprice=web %>% html_node("#price_inside_buybox")%>% html_text())
}

Price_Check<- web_scrape("https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iPhone-GSM-Unlocked-64GB/dp/B0775MV9K2/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=iphone&qid=1580911472&sr=8-3")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is working for me. I get a data frame with one cell reading "\n        $289.99\n "

Comment: Seems to work fine with me. Try with `html_node(xpath="//span[@id='priceblock_ourprice']") %>% html_text()` to understand if there's a problem with your css selector (although this selects the price located in the product page, not in the buybox).